# GCC add further binary in linkerscript

Tags: gcc, linker, bootloader, linker-scripts

I got two applications one is a bootloader and second one is an application. This application shall be kept.

How can I embed the bootloader binary to the linker script of the application (this is only for debugging purposes)?

What are the steps?

I have defined a new section called `.bootloader` but I don't know how to get further and which kind of format the bootloader should have to succeed with this. I use the, currently latest ARM GNU embedded toolchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in the linker script you can use the [`INPUT`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/simple-commands.html) command. Like `INPUT(bootloader.o)`. Or maybe even `STARTUP` if the order is important for you.

Otherwise you can use `arm-none-eabi-objcopy`.

Here's similar question from Electrical Engineering https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/368926/95998